# Subtract values in a .csv

Tags: python

So i have a .csv that has this structure:

```
,x-Koordinate,y-Koordinate,LASER
1,51.972,1433.401
2,,,LASER_ON
3,41.972,1433.401
4,41.972,1438.401
5,51.97,1438.401
6,,,LASER_OFF
7,51.972,1382.401
8,,,LASER_ON
9,41.972,1382.401
```

I want to perform a subtraction that takes the X and Y values of a line and subtracts the X and Y values of the line before.(If the line before is LASER_ON/LAser_OFF it should take the X and Y value that came before. For example:

```
3,((X line 3) - (X line 1) = new X line 3), ((Y line 3) - (Y line1) = new Y line 3)

4,((X line 4) - (X line 3) = new X line 4), ((Y line 4) - (Y line3) = new Y line 4)
```

Without the LASER_ON/LASER_OFF statements it worked like this.

```
import pandas as pd

def subtract_previous_value(csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

   
    if 'x-Koordinate' not in df.columns or 'y-Koordinate' not in df.columns:
        print("Error: The CSV file must have 'x-Koordinate' and 'y-Koordinate' columns.")
        return

    first_row = df[['x-Koordinate', 'y-Koordinate']].iloc[0:1]

    df['X-Koordinate'] = df['x-Koordinate'] - df['x-Koordinate'].shift(1)
    df['Y-Koordinate'] = df['y-Koordinate'] - df['y-Koordinate'].shift(1)


    df = df.drop(['x-Koordinate', 'y-Koordinate'], axis=1)

    df.loc[0, 'X-Koordinate'] = first_row['x-Koordinate'].iloc[0]
    df.loc[0, 'Y-Koordinate'] = first_row['y-Koordinate'].iloc[0]

    print("Original DataFrame:")
    print(df)

    df.to_csv(new_csv_file, index=False)
    print(f"\nResult saved to {new_csv_file}")

subtract_previous_value(end_csv_file)
```

I want to subtract the values from each other and write it in a new .csv but my script doesnt work now because LASER_ON/OFF commands are included with coordinate values.  Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: What exactly can we help you with?  Please state your question explicitly in the question.

Comment: I want to subtract the values from eachother and write it in a new .csv but my skript doesnt work anymore because there are not only coordinate values but also the LASER_ON/OFF commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly and your csv structure remains the same, you just need to use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). See the code below:

```
df2 = df.copy() # keep the original values

# update x-coord 
df2['x-Koordinate'] = df2['x-Koordinate'] - df2['x-Koordinate'].fillna(method='ffill').shift(1)
df2['x-Koordinate'] = df2['x-Koordinate'].fillna(df['x-Koordinate'].fillna(method='ffill'))

# update y-coord
df2['y-Koordinate'] = df2['y-Koordinate'] - df2['y-Koordinate'].fillna(method='ffill').shift(1)
df2['y-Koordinate'] = df2['y-Koordinate'].fillna(df['y-Koordinate'].fillna(method='ffill'))

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   x-Koordinate  y-Koordinate      LASER
0        51.972      1433.401        NaN
1        51.972      1433.401   LASER_ON
2       -10.000         0.000        NaN
3         0.000         5.000        NaN
4         9.998         0.000        NaN
5        51.970      1438.401  LASER_OFF
6         0.002       -56.000        NaN
7        51.972      1382.401   LASER_ON
8       -10.000         0.000        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. How could  i change this so the X and Y coordinate columns stay empty when there is a LASER_ON/OFF command in the row. Or should i just delete them afterwards?

Comment: You can either null those manually, or just change the second line to `df2['x-Koordinate'].fillna(df['x-Koordinate'])`